# How to get kill command result in bash script

Tags: bash, kill

I have a bash script which run a command to get its result and do something depends on the result. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
commandResult=$(($myCommand) 2>&1)
if [[ "$commandResult" == *Error* ]]; then 
    x="failed"
else
    x="success"
fi
echo $x
exit 0;
```

There is no problem with this script, the issue is when I try to kill `$myCommand` in the middle of running the script via `kill -9 $myCommand` in command line, the `$commandResult` will be null and the "success" will be printed.

How could I put the kill result in the `$commandResult` or any other way to find out if process killed in this script?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should be checking your command's exit code, not its output to standard error. `myCommand` should exit with 0 on success, and some non-zero code on failure. If it is killed via the `kill` command, it's exit code will automatically be 128+n, where n is the signal you used to kill it. Then you can test for success with

```
if myCommand; then
    echo success
    exit 0
else
    status=$?
    echo failure
    exit $status
fi
```

Also, you probably [don't need to use `kill -9`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...). Start with `kill` (which sends the gentler `TERM` signal); if that doesn't work, step up to `kill -2` (`INT`, equivalent of Ctrl-C).